# Could not deduce (Show a10) arising from a use of ‘def’

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

I have been stuck on this error for quite a while. I'm not sure if I am being stupid but I cannot see where it is coming from...

The data type `Settings` is defined as so:

```
data Settings a = Settings { 
         _nodeDrawFunction :: a -> Diagram B
       , _dynamicHead :: Measure Double
       , _dynamicThick :: Measure Double
       , _directed :: Directed
       , _horizontalOrientation :: Maybe Bool
       , _layerSpacing :: Maybe Double
       , _nodeSpacing :: Maybe Double
       , _graphPadding :: Maybe Double
       , _colF :: Maybe (Int -> Colour Double)
       , _bgOp :: Maybe Double
       , _initPos :: Maybe Int
      }
```

And `makeLenses ''Settings` is used to create lenses for each record. The default for `_drawNodeFunction` is `drawDefaultNode`.

When I create a function overwriting some of these values using Lens setters it works fine, for example:

```
test1 :: (Show a) => Graph a -> Settings a
test1 g = def & bgOp .~ Just 1
```

Which works as expected. The type of `Graph` is from the library algebraic-graphs.

If I try to set `nodeDrawFunction`, for example with:

```
test2 :: (Show a) => Graph a -> Settings a
test2 g = def & nodeDrawFunction .~ drawDefaultNode
              & bgOp .~ Just 1
```

The following error is produced:

```
Could not deduce (Show a10) arising from a use of ‘def’
  from the context: Show a
    bound by the type signature for:
               test2 :: forall a. Show a => Graph a -> Settings a
    at Visualise/Hierarchical.hs:78:1-42
  The type variable ‘a10’ is ambiguous
  These potential instances exist:
    instance Show n => Show (Duration n) -- Defined in ‘Data.Active’
    instance Show n => Show (Era n) -- Defined in ‘Data.Active’
    instance Show n => Show (Time n) -- Defined in ‘Data.Active’
    ...plus 74 others
    ...plus 264 instances involving out-of-scope types
    (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
• In the first argument of ‘(&)’, namely ‘def’
  In the first argument of ‘(&)’, namely
    ‘def & nodeDrawFunction .~ drawDefaultNode’
  In the expression:
    def & nodeDrawFunction .~ drawDefaultNode & bgOp .~ Just 1
```

Even if I try to set `nodeDrawFunction` to the default value (as well as any other valid function).

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably intend that `def` and `def & nodeDrawFunction .~ drawDefaultNode` have the same type.  `nodeDrawFunction` is flexible enough to allow them to have different types, `Settings a` and `Settings a10`.  GHC is starting with this more general assumption, and then can't pick a specific type for `a10`, since it's not constrained by anything in the function.

One option is to define `nodeDrawFunction` with a less general type.

Another option is to add a type signature on `def` to guide GHC.  I think this will work if you add `-XScopedTypeVariables`:

```
(def :: Settings a) & nodeDrawFunction .~ drawDefaultNode
```

Without [ScopedTypeVariables](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#lexically-scoped-type-variables) the two type variables `a` are interpreted as different, and given different unique names before type checking.  If you had multiple fields in `Settings` that involve `a`, `makeLenses` would derive lenses that cannot change `a`, since no single-field lens could do so.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'd tried this but forgotten to enable the ScopedTypeVariables extension :)

Comment: ScopedTypeVariables is on my short list of "would like to see enabled by default in future GHC" :)